# Marketing Cloud Journey Results

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, api, integration

We use marketing cloud to send about 3000 emails to Customers once in every 2 weeks.

Out of these 3000 emails, we have about 20-30 hard bounces and 10-20 soft bounces.

As of now, we track these hard bounces after 24 hours of journey execution and getting the stats from the email logs for that specific journey.

Then we do a VLOOKUP of those bounce stats with our customer records from Account object in salesforce.

Marketing Cloud Subscriber Key is the same as salesforce 18 digit Id in Account object.

Is there a way for us to get in the email send result (hard/soft bounce, success etc) via API ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Marketing Clouds Data View tables. Has all the the data you need. (Sends, Bounces, Opens, Unsubscribes)

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Comment: Thanks. Can I extract the bounce data from Data View tables ,using REST API, back into Salesforce ?

Comment: Can't do it via REST API. Two ways to do it that I'm familiar with:

1. Use the "Data Extract" tool in Automation Studio to extract the data from SFMC and send to an SFTP. Then have a job from your Data Engineering function pipe this data into your Data Warehouse.

2. Use a Data Connector like Fivetran to pass this data on the back-end directly.
https://fivetran.com/docs/applications/salesforce-marketing-cloud